# How can i add some element into json file using python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

this is json `{"name": ["Juan", "Alex"]}`.
how can i add something to "name", using python?
thanks in advance for your reply.
This is my code, he is don't work :(

```
import json

enteredString = str(input())
json_file = 'list_of_workers.json'
data = json.load(open(json_file, "rb"))
data['name'].append(enteredString)
json.dump(data, open(json_file, "wb"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

enteredString = str(input())
json_file = 'list_of_workers.json' 
data = json.load(open(json_file, "rb"))
data['name'].append(enteredString)
newdata = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)  
with open(json_file, 'w') as f:   
    f.write(newdata)
```